# Folder copy including files in gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm trying to copy 2 folders onto a single build folder and for the second path I want to copy whole libs folder including libs folder itself to destination.

```
var paths = {
    'standalone' : '../app-ui/assets/js',
    'standalone_libs' : '../app-ui/libs',
    'destination' : '../SomeFolder'
}

gulp.task('folder-copy', function() {

    return gulp.src([paths.standalone_js + '/*', paths.standalone_libs + '/*']).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.destination));
});

Structure according to code
->SomeFolder
   ->app.js [ file from ../app-ui/assets/js ]
   -> angular/angular.js [ file from ../app-ui/libs ]
   -> lodash/lodash.js   [ file from ../app-ui/libs ]

Actual Structure wanted
->SomeFolder
   ->app.js [ file from ../app-ui/assets/js ]
   -> libs
          -> angular/angular.js [ file from ../app-ui/libs ]
          -> lodash/lodash.js   [ file from ../app-ui/libs ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could specify the base in gulp.src :

```
return gulp.src(['some/path/app/*', 'libs/**/*'], {base: '.'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
```

This will copy all your files in libs, with the directory structure intact. But the directory structure will be preserved for app.js also...

I would just do two separate copy.
You can use [merge-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream). There's a [recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/using-multiple-sources-in-one-task.md) in gulp repository. It would boil down to something like this :

```
var merge = require('merge-stream')

var libs= gulp.src('libs/**/*', {base: '.'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));

var app = gulp.src('app.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));

return merge(libs, app);
```

Comment: yeah i don't want the directory structure to be preserved for app.js

Comment: how can i chain two separate copies ?

Comment: I added an example in my answer :)

Comment: A bit verbose for a simple copy but yeah... 
Don't forget to mark your question as solved (if it is indeed solved)
Cheers

Comment: i get a merge stream error "Unhandled stream error in pipe"

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `/*` because this means the whole content inside the folder is what you want.

So for the libs, I would not add the `/*` like follows

```
 return gulp.src([paths.standalone_js + '/*', paths.standalone_libs ]).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.destination));
```

Comment: this would create a empty libs folder

Answer (score 0):

What about changing this:

```
var paths = {
    'standalone' : '../app-ui/assets/js',
    'standalone_libs' : '../app-ui/libs',
    'destination' : '../SomeFolder'
}
```

to this:

```
var paths = {
    'standalone' : '../app-ui/assets/js',
    'standalone_libs' : '../app-ui/(libs)',
    'destination' : '../SomeFolder'
}
```

Comment: How would renaming ../app-ui/libs to ../app-ui/(libs) help ?

Comment: gulp.src uses glob and in glb you can use kind of regex to find folders and files ( see `*`) so, it copies all the folders it finds, so let him finding the folder might help (not tested, I will later on)